# Can't post to facebook page by email from php

Tags: php, email, facebook-page

you can send a status update to a facebook page you own by sending it to a cretin (secret) email address. this is described here:
http://www.facebook.com/help/pages/mobile
the problem is I cant make it work from php

```
function page_publish_by_mail($page_mail, $status){
    $to = $page_mail;
    $subject = $status;
    $message = "";
    $headers = "From: my@mail.address";   
    return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

I can send mail to my email address and I can post by mail from my email address but I can't seem to post by mail from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to send to facebook mail before, however I feel like it is being filtered out due to lack of header information.  Try adding some more header details.

I always send headers like this:

```
$headers  = 'From: Your Name <youremail@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
```

This is set up to send an html email, but you might try other content-types if that doesn't work.

It may be a good idea to look in the documentation and see if there are other headers that are required as well.